# What is "Field List" command in mysql processlist?

Tags: mysql, process

In my processlist, I see a long running process. There is no query, just the command "Field List" with an empty info column. Its been waiting almost 20 minutes on a table meta data lock on an unspecified table.

Googling for "MySQL command Field List" hasn't returned anything useful. Can someone tell me what this command is trying to do and what may have caused it?

*Using MySQL 5.6.35* on a *CentOS* 6 box

[image]

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Look for any lines in the `PROCESSLIST` with a Time higher than that one (1188).  It *probably* indicates the villain.  The owner of both rows may give a clue.

A "metadata lock" involves something other than simple queries -- possibly `ALTER TABLE` or `LOCK TABLES` (as for `mysqldump`), etc.

"Field list" sounds like probing `information_schema` for the columns in the table, but I could be wrong.

Another possibility is that there is an open transaction that is waiting to be `COMMITted`.  (And it is 'between' statements when the `PROCESSLIST` was grabbed.)

`SHOW OPEN TABLES;` might give another clue.

Comment: Probably should have included in the question that its the longest running process. The information_schema part makes sense though

Comment: I added another thought -- on transactions.  And `SHOW OPEN TABLES;`